# Why do I keep getting a TypeError: setScrollNav is not a function, when function is defined

Tags: reactjs, scroll, use-effect

I am trying to use React Scroll, but with this code in place whenever I scroll I get error:

```
TypeError: setScrollNav is not a function
```

```
export default function Navbar() {
    const [showNav, setShowNav] = useState(false);

    const setScrollNav = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        function changeNav() {
            if(window.scrollY >= 100) {
                setScrollNav(true)
            } else {
                setScrollNav(false)
            }
        }
        window.addEventListener('scroll', changeNav)
        return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', changeNav)
}, [setScrollNav])
return (
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the syntax of `useState`

```
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
```

It returns an array, the second element of the array is the dispatch function.

Comment: It still keeps throwing the error

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the code above that:

const [showNav, setShowNav] = useState(false);

Comment: you can't write `setScrollNav = useState(false)`

Comment: Alright I will try something else thank you!